# display a series of images in Excel 2010 using VBA

Tags: image, excel, excel-2010, vba

As part of a larger project I need to display a series of images within the one macro. When I run this it displays the final image after the last msgbox, with the others layered underneath:

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim x As Integer
Dim Pic As Object
Dim picname As String
For x = 1 To 7
picname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "pic" & x & ".png"
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picname).Select
MsgBox (x)
Next x
End Sub
```

The Msgbox command is there to slow the process down so that I can see, or in this case not see, the pictures change.

The images are called pic1.png, pic2.png etc

How do I get the separate images to show during the macro?

RE-EDIT:

So here is the picture function and the larger function which plays a randomised piece of Musique Concret.

```
Private Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
```

***showpic** gives an image relative to the pitch of the sound being played.*

```
Function showpic(value)
Dim v As Integer
v = value
picname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "pic" & v & ".png"
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture (picname), True, True, a1, a1, 170, 170
DoEvents
End Function
```

***play** runs a series of specific sound files generated by a randomised process choosing instrument and pitch and creating the requisite filename. The "piece" runs for 'notes' seconds and is triggered by a separate macro that changes the value in a given 'cell' to match the 'condition'.*

```
Function play(Cell, condition, notes)
Dim WAVFile As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
Dim currentcell As String
Dim pitchcell As String
Const SND_SYNC = &H0
Const SND_ASYNC = &H1
Const SND_FILENAME = &H20000
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
For x = 1 To notes
If Evaluate(Cell.value & condition) Then
y = x + 65
z = x + 39
c = Chr(y)
d = Chr(z)
If y > 90 Then c = "A" & d
currentcell = c & 6
pitchcell = c & 3
showpic (Sheets("Sheet1").Range(pitchcell).value)
WAVFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range(currentcell).Text & ".wav"
Call PlaySound(WAVFile, 0&, SND_SYNC)
End If
Next x
ErrHandler:
play = False
Exit Function
End Function
```

I have three problems:

1. It doesn't show the first image file
2. It performs a 'calculate' or F9 at the beginning so re-randomises the piece and doesn't play the displayed sequence; I presume this is caused by the first DoEvents.
3. It now plays twice! However, the second time through it does show all the image files.

Comment: Trying adding a `DoEvents` call after each Insert.

Comment: DoEvents should work. see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738712/updating-caption-on-activex-button-in-excel-vba/12739638#12739638)

Comment: Tried adding DoEvents. It would work correctly running it from within the VBA environment but not when activating using a button on the worksheet.

Comment: You only added part of your code update. How is showpic being called? In what context?

Comment: You asked Daniel! Have re-edited above.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Since my initial answer didn't work for you, how about achieving your results a completely different way. This method using [Application.OnTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx) to re-run your sub and insert the next picture.

```
Sub NextPicture()
    Static x As Integer
    Dim pic As Object
    Dim picname As String
    'Reset x to 0 because I assumed you want to rotate through the pictures.
    'If you want it to stop replace with If x = 7 then exit sub
    If x = 7 Then x = 0
    x = x + 1
    picname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "pic" & x & ".png"
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picname).Select
    'Using 00:00:05 = 5 seconds, change the amount to speed up or slow down the picture changes
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "NextPicture"
End Sub
```

---

**Original Answer**
I could not get your code to work, but I could if I used [Shapes.AddPicture](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080554003.aspx), which is actually more robust because you get/have to specify the location and size.

Syntax:

```
expression.AddPicture(Filename, LinkToFile, SaveWithDocument, Left, Top, Width, Height)
```

Example:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(picname, True, True, 100, 100, 70, 70)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Ironically I had used AddPicture earlier but changed when I used Record Macro to see if I could get something that worked better! I now have:
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture (picname), True, True, a1, a1, 170, 170
but even with DoEvents it still doesn't work for me!

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to give a completely different way of doing what I think you want to accomplish using most of your original code.

Comment: Liked your idea; needed to write code so have edited my original post above.